# React Native Invalid Product ID in In-App Purchases

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, payment

[image]this is my code where i am getting products added on app store. before i was was working fine. when i remove the previous products on app store and added new then it's stop working. i removed the previous products from app store but still i can get that products by using their id. i clear build restart xcode but nothing works.

```
  const itemSkus = Platform.select({
    ios: ['pkg01', 'pkg02'],
    android: ['pkg01', 'pkg02'],
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeConnection();

    purchaseUpdateSubscription = purchaseUpdatedListener(async purchase => {
      const receipt = purchase.transactionReceipt;
      if (receipt) {
        try {
          if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            RNIap.finishTransactionIOS(purchase.transactionId);
          }
          console.log('receipt: ', purchase.transactionReceipt);
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(e);
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);

  const initializeConnection = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await RNIap.initConnection();
      console.log('connection is => ', result);
      
      if (result) {
        await getProducts()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error in cdm => ', err);
    }
  };
  const getProducts = async () => {
     const products = await RNIap.getProducts(itemSkus);
      console.log('Products', products);
      setProductList(products);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a combination of a few things:

1. Apple could be caching the old product IDs, it may take some time but they will become unavailable.
2. The new product IDs might need to be reviewed/approved by Apple to ensure they abide by their [rules](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#3.1.2) before they are made available. Until that happens you won't be able to access them for in app purchases.